# Accessing Context in React Native

Tags: react-native, use-context

in react native i have the following files:

**App.js**

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Children from './Child';
import { MyProvider } from './context/Context';
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyProvider>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Children />
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    </MyProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Child.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { useMain } from './context/Context';

const Child = () => {
  const { dummy, setDummy } = useMain();
  const onPressLearnMore = () => {
    setDummy('c');
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This children {dummy}</Text>
      <Button onPress={onPressLearnMore} title="click" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

**Context.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
export const mainContext = React.createContext();

export function useMain() {
  return useContext(mainContext);
}
export function MyProvider({ children }) {
  const [dummy, setDummy] = useState('a');
  useEffect(() => {
    setDummy('b');
  }, []);
  function doNull() {
    console.log('do null');
  }
  const value = {
    dummy,
    setDummy,
  };
  return <mainContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</mainContext.Provider>;
}
```

Everything works as expected, Children component can access { dummy } and { setDummy }, so that i can place all my "shared" functions, states and so on in Context to be used from everywhere.
I was just wondering if i can access them in App.js too without coding another component; it looks if i import

```
import { useMain } from './context/Context';
```

and then i add this

```
const { dummy, setDummy } = useMain();
```

to my App, it does not work, so i'm thinking i can only access things from context only in  child, but the first View is a child too!

Should i create a new component if i need access to Context or can it be accessed from the MyProvider level too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first view is a child of your provider indeed but `App` is not, so yes you would need to extract your view as a separate component if you want to access your context from it.

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Children from './Child';
import { MyProvider, useMain } from './context/Context';
import React from 'react';

const Container = () => {
  const { dummy, setDummy } = useMain();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Children />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyProvider>
      <Container />
    </MyProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Perfect! thank you for your confirmation, that was what i was assuming